# refiner accuracy index in SP13

Tags: 2013, search-results, enterprise-search, refiner

Is there a way to define the refiner accuracy index in SharePoint 2013? 
Is there a way of applying it to the REST service calls?

The totalrows and the refiner counts I'm getting on the REST calls are clearly some type of guesstimate. Especially when there are not many results, it's obviously wrong, and it damages the credibility of the system.

In the example I was looking at yesterday, I had refined the results down to 4 records, and most refiners were still showing (5)

Any way of forcing accuracy up to 500 records for both the refiners and the totalrows?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen anything definitive - however it doesn't appear that Search in 2013 inherited the deep refiners (in regards to how it gets it count) and instead uses the same estimating engine that was present in 2010.  This would explain why for the most part - the count property is not enabled with the refiners (just like in 2010, but not like with FAST).

Like 2010 it appears you options are to custom code your refiners to get the count accuracy you need or to use a 3rd party product like Surfay (which has a number of other enhancements to search as well).  I would think this would be possible with a custom display template and REST API(which should return more accurate results as you will get the count of returned results ste).

Comment: I would expect the REST API to give me the right numbers, but it doesn't. If I limit it to 10 results, the rowcount will be 10 (which makes sense) but the totalresults field still will return the same estimated figure we see in the "about" text on the UI